# Scatter-plot with transparent markers in GNU Octave

Tags: octave, transparency, scatter-plot

I need to draw a scatter-plot with semitransparent filled markers.
As an example I need to set alpha color on the filled markers in the following code.

I'm using `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` and Octave 4.0.3 on Debian 9 Stretch.

I know that in Matlab is possible to modify the transparency of the markers on the scatter plots. I need to have the same in Octave 4.0.3

```
clf
h=figure(1);

n = 100;
x = randn(n, 1);
y = randn(n, 1);
S = rand(n, 1)*50;
hold on
s1=scatter(x(1:50), y(1:50), S(1:50), 'red', "filled")
s2=scatter(x(51:100), y(51:100), S(51:100), "green", "filled")

set(s1,'edgecolor','none');
set(s1,'facealpha',0.2);
set(s2,'edgecolor','none');
set(s2,'facealpha',0.2);
```

this code produces the following figure.

```
hold off
saveas(h, 'bubbleplot.png');
```

[image: example bubbleplot]

Comment: Please add a MCVE, you above snippet can't be run beause s1 is undefined. ALso add used graphics_toolkit and GNU Octave version

Comment: Thank you I  added the info in the post. I'm using graphics_toolkit('gnuplot') on Debian 9 stretch

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are out of luck. Octave (even as of 5.1.0) only supports alpha transparency for patch and surface plots, not for markers in scatter or line plots.

You can [submit a GNU Octave bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave) requesting support for this.

Comment: Thank you! I read some posts pointing out that octave doesn't support transparency on Markers. I'll follow your advice.